# Add column in postgresql JSON

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I am using postgresql 9.4

I have one json column in the table and it contains the value:

```
"{
  "title" : "risk",
  "name"  : "David"
}"
```

I have to perform two functionality

1. *Update* the name value to **"John"**
2. *Insert* the **"city" : "paris"**

my final value should be in my table column

```
"{
  "title" : "risk",
  "name"  : "John",
  "city"  : "paris"
}"
```

Basically, I want update and insert query for this json column and I can not change the database to higher version

Comment: Hi. Please read [ask]. Please explain how the documentation doesn't tell you this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

smth like:

```
update table 
set jbcolumn = json_build_object('title',jbcolumn->>'title','name','John','city','Paris') where bcolumn->>'name' = 'David
```

in postgres 9.4

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-json.html

> json_build_object(VARIADIC "any")

Comment: I have tried this but getting ERROR :
 function json_build_object(unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown) does not exist

Comment: This was helped me somewhat but need to update little bit

Answer (score 1):

There is useful `||` operator for JSON type in the later versions of PostgreSQL. For 9.4 version you can to create it yourself:

```
create function my_json_cat(json, json) returns json stable strict language sql as $$
  select json_object_agg(coalesce(x.key, y.key), coalesce(y.value, x.value))
  from json_each($1) as x full join json_each($2) as y on (x.key = y.key)
$$;

create operator || (
  leftarg=json, rightarg=json,
  procedure=my_json_cat);


with t(x,y) as (values('{
  "title" : "risk",
  "name"  : "David"
}'::json, '{
  "title" : "risk",
  "name"  : "John",
  "city"  : "paris"
}'::json))
select x || y from t;
```

So your final statement could be

```
update your_table set
  your_column = your_column || '{"name": "John", "city": "paris"}'
where ...
```

After upgrade to the later version of PostgreSQL just remove function and operator declarations from your DB script, nothing else should be changed.

[Demo.](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.4&fiddle=bf8e6269e32ac0c8b53484fff2542b82)